# Why columns are not all the same height?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Kotlin with Jetpack Compose for an Android app and I'm facing a problem that I'm struggling to solve. This is the result when I run the code below with `COLUMNS` equals to `7`:

[image]

This is the result with `COLUMNS` equals to `8`:

[image]

As you can see some times the columns are not all the same height (you can see the black background).
How to solve this problem?

I tested the code below on 3 different devices and these are some the results:

With `COLUMNS = 7`:

- with `Google Pixel 2`: the first column is shorter than the others (first image)
- with `Google Pixel C`: the last 4 columns are shorter than the others
- with `Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite`: the first column is shorter than the others

With `COLUMNS = 8`

- with `Google Pixel 2`: the first 4 columns are shorter than the others
- with `Google Pixel C`: the first 4 columns are shorter than the others
- with `Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite`: the first 4 columns are shorter than the others

I simplified the code as much as possible to find the problem but still I can't find it:

```kotlin
package com.example.test

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.aspectRatio
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import com.example.test.ui.theme.TestTheme
import kotlin.random.Random

const val COLUMNS = 11

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestTheme {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Table(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(.9f))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Table(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(modifier = modifier.background(Color.Black)) {
        for (columnIndex in 0 until COLUMNS) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color(Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256), Random.nextInt(256)))
                    .weight(1f)
            ) {
                for (rowIndex in 0 until 5) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)) {
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            // TODO
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of rounding. You want to split some horizontal space `W` evenly between `N` columns. And when `W mod N != 0`, some columns will be 1 pixel narrower than the rest. The number of narrower columns depends on the device width and number of columns, as you realized.

You then put 5 boxes with `aspectRatio(1f)` in each column, meaning the height of the column is 5 times its width, so the height difference is 5 pixels.

Comment: I added `.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to the Row composable, `.fillMaxHeight()` and `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly` to columns. It's not pixel-perfect but for me is enough, thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. There are multiple solutions depending on what you want I guess. For example, if you wouldn't mind that the columns won't take all the available width, you can round all the widths down... you will need custom layout for that though I guess.